# iOS In-App Purchase: Managing multiple auto-renewal subscription families

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

In our application, we support four types of subscription like:

- Single User Monthly Subscription
- Single User Yearly Subscription
- Family User Monthly Subscription
- Family User Yearly Subscription

and we divide these subscription in two family like below:

1. Single User Subscription

   - Single User Monthly Subscription
   - Single User Yearly Subscription
2. Family User Subscription

   - Family User Monthly Subscription
   - Family User Yearly Subscription

we have some query to understand the auto-renewal flow, which I listed:

1. Can user switch between auto-renewal product families from iTunes Manage Subscription / from Application?
2. Suppose I purchase Single user monthly subscription and now I want to switch to family user monthly subscription.

   - Which options, iTunes manage subscription will show when I try to change subscription means it display both subscription family or only family in which I currently subscribed?
   - if I purchase these different family subscription, Apple will charge at that time or will charge after current subscription expire?
3. Suppose I purchase Family User Yearly Subscription and now I want to switch to Family User Monthly Subscription.

   - Can I able to purchase "Family User Monthly Subscription" because as i already subscribed with same family subscription which is "Family User Yearly Subscription"?
   - When I change these subscription from iTunes manage subscription, new subscription will start when current subscription expire and will charge from new subscription at that time.
     Am I correct with Apple subscription flow?
4. Are we violating any Apple policy by managing two auto-renewal family in our application?

Comment: Does this post answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890962/ios-in-app-purchase-managing-multiple-auto-renewable-subscriptions-with-upgrade/35896921#35896921

Comment: @Marc:- I read your post, it's really helped me. but still i have confuse about managing subscription product family from iTunes Manage different subscription.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Can user switch between auto-renewal product families from iTunes Manage Subscription / from Application?

Yes, users will be able to switch between `Monthly` and `Yearly` but not between `Single` and `Family` unless they are of the same Subscription Family.

> 2. - Which options, iTunes manage subscription will show when i try to change subscription means it display both subscription family or only family in which i currently subscribed?

It will only show the options for the other products in the same Subscription Family. So if the only other option is `Yearly` then it will only show that.

> 2. - if i purchase these different family subscription, Apple will charge at that time or will charge after current subscription expire?

Apple will only charge the user once the original subscription duration is over, e.g. if a user buys a `Yearly` subscription then 8 months later she switches to `Monthly`, there is still 4 more months until the yearly subscription ends so she will be billed for the `Monthly` subscription in 4 months.

> 3. - Can i able to purchase "Family User Monthly Subscription" because as i already subscribed with same family subscription which is "Family User Yearly Subscription"?

Yes, users can change the subscription to any other product of the same Subscription Family.

> 3. - When i change these subscription from iTunes manage subscription, new subscription will start when current subscription expire and will charge from new subscription at that time. Am i correct with Apple subscription flow?

The new subscription will start immediately, effectively replacing the old one, however the user will not be billed until the pro-rata credit of the original subscription is exhausted.

> 4. Are we violating any Apple policy by managing two auto-renewal family in our application?

Not that I am aware of, if in doubt seek clarification from Apple or a lawyer.

---

One final note. It seems as though you may want your `Single User` and `Family User` durations to be in the same Subscription Family, otherwise a user could purchase both kinds subscriptions which i'm not sure that is what you want. It also prevents users from switching from `Single` to `Family` or vice-versa which may frustrate some users.

Comment: thanks for your effort , but can you please give me a reference , because i need to know more about apple subscription